# How I can find the method(GET and POST) in a link Using Selenium web driver?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, automation, selenium-grid, browser-automation

I have to search all the POST and GET in my project. Suppose I enter a link and Login to the system. The Web driver should searches all the Get and Post in that page.

Comment: Please read [ask]. Please provide the code you have tried and the execution result including any error messages, etc. Also provide a link to the page and/or the relevant HTML.

Answer (score 0):

I had used

```
   List<WebElement> listmethod = driver.findelements(By.TagName("form"));
for(WebElement listcall : listmethod){
System.out.println(listcall.getAttributes("method"));
}
```

it solved my problem